# What is the advantage of applying a complex hash function and then taking mod n instead of simply doing mod n for the input?

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

In hashing, we take the input and apply some complex hashing algorithm. Then, we do mod n to find the bucket or server into which this input needs to be sent.
Hash input x -> Hash(x) -> Divide by n - >Hash(x) mod n gives location of the bucket.

If we take the input directly without hashing, it is equivalent to having an identity hash function. Hash(x) =x .. mod n..Wikipedia calls this function a 'trivial' hash function.

Generally,hash(x) is a complex hashing algorithm such as MD5, SHA etc...
Q1) Regardless of how we hash it, it just boils down to a value between 0 and n-1(reminder when divided by n). So, how does the choice of hashing function matter? 
Q2) I know that an ideal hash function distributes the input values uniformly across the buckets. In this aspect, are those complex hashing functions superior to the hash identity function?

Assume that the input is always an integer.

Comment: What is the "hash identity function," at least as it relates to your question?  BTW...I agree with everything else you mentioned in your question.

Comment: In Mathematics, a function that returns the input value as the output is called an identity function...f(x)=x... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function.

Comment: Yes, complex hashing functions (e.g. a cryptographic function) are superior to using something more trivial, assuming the former do actually bucket inputs in a more even way.

Comment: 'assuming that the.....'  That is my question actually. If they do it, they are superior. That is obvious. My question is - will they do it? Is that assumption right? If not, then those complex hashing algorithms will simply be an overkill.

Comment: I agree that if the hashing function is complex and does a lousy job of even bucketing, then it doesn't serve much purpose.  In app languages such as Java, the hashing functions actually tend to be fairly simple.  Poke around the source code if you have time to do that.

Comment: For cryptography, hash functions are designed to very demanding standards. For hash tables, hash functions are designed to distribute inputs well and be very fast to compute. A cryptographic hash function is definitely overkill for hash table application, and a hash function designed for hash tables would be hopeless weak for cryptography purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the advantage of applying a complex hash function and then taking mod n instead of simply doing mod n for the input?

Let's look at a simple example.  Say our keys are 100 pointers to some objects in memory that are 8-byte aligned: that means the 3 least-significant bits are always 0s.  Our table size is currently 128 buckets.  We mod the pointer values by 128 before hashing, we're effectively taking:

```
 32-bit pointer bits   xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx000
             mod 128   00000000 00000000 00000000 0xxxx000
```

Notice that only 4 potentially meaningful bits from the pointer make it through to our hash function, which means *at most* 16 distinct values reach the hash function: our 100 pointers will collide into only 16 buckets, which means collision chains will typically be 7 or 8 deep even for the strongest hash function.  That's woeful given we had 128 buckets for 100 keys: we should have had mostly 0,  1 or 2 keys mapped to any given bucket.

Now, what would have happened if we'd had 100 pointers to memory mapped areas, each 4096-byte page aligned?  They all would have mapped to the same bucket.

Not doing the mod operation until the end ensures higher order bits in the keys can help randomise the lower order bit positions in the hash value, and those lower-significance bits can affect the bucket the key maps to.  (Another thing that can help a bit is ensuring the table size is a prime number, but that's best used in combination with doing the mod after hashing.  As a random sampling, GNU's C++ compiler uses prime bucket counts for Standard Library hash tables, while Visual C++ uses powers of two (and for long strings faster but weaker hash functions))

> Q1) Regardless of how we hash it, it just boils down to a value between 0 and n-1(reminder when divided by n). So, how does the choice of hashing function matter?

Obviously if our hash function was `h(key) { return 0 }` every key would collide at bucket 0.  At the other extreme, a crytographic hash function should effectively randomly-but-repeatedly map any given key to a given bucket, such that any bit changing anywhere in the key creates a completely uncorrelated mapping.  That helps protect you from excessive collisions with keys that don't vary at many bit positions.  But, strong hash functions tend to take longer to calculate, and the reduction in collisions may or may not result in a net performance win.  It's sometimes worth choosing the strength of the hash function based on knowledge of how much the keys are likely to differ from each other.

> Q2) I know that an ideal hash function distributes the input values uniformly across the buckets. In this aspect, are those complex hashing functions superior to the hash identity function?

At the extreme, identity hash functions hope that the input numbers will map onto distinct buckets with more probability than a crytographic strength hash function would: for example, if we hash 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 into a table using an identity function, they're dense (close to each other) and span just 6 values (5 through 10), so as long as the table size is >= 6 (e.g. prime value 7) they're guaranteed not to collide.  But, identity hash functions given collision prone inputs (e.g. pointers cast to numbers) are a disaster as they've done nothing to mix in more-significant bits with less-significant bits before the mod kicks in - same problem explained for pointers above.

Summarily, identity hash functions can have better average-case performance for common integer keys, but have far worse worst-case performance for non-dense, non-random / collision-prone keys.

Comment: Q1) ".................. that are 8-byte aligned: that means the 3 least-significant bits are always 0s" - Always 0s. Can you explain this?
Q2)mod 128 - 00000000 00000000 00000000 0xxxx000    .. Only four bits change? mod 128 means reminder when divided by 128. so, it means any value between 0 and 127. How can all those numbers be represented in the above format?  eg...1 is 000.............1 does not fit into the pattern.

Comment: On some architectures/CPUs, particular types of variables may either be required to be at memory addresses that are a multiple of a particular number, or operations on such addresses may just be faster.  For example, `double` variables are often best or necessarily stored at addresses that are an exact multiple of 8.  Valid addresses would therefore be `(double*)0`, `(double*)8`, `(double*)16`, `(double*)24` etc, but if you tried to read or write through `(double*)4` your program might crash or operate slower.  These "8 byte aligned" addresses always have their 3 least significant bits clear.

Comment: @PraveenNvs: So, consider an 8-byte aligned address like say 0x4570: mod it by 128 and you get 112 decimal, 0x4578 is the next aligned address and the mod 128 produces 120 decimal, then 0x4580 mod 128 is back to 0.  You take all the 8-byte aligned pointers and mod them by 128, and you'll always get the same 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104, 112, or 120 - the same 8 values, not all 128 values between 0 and 127 inclusive.

Comment: *"How can all those numbers be represented in the above format? eg...1 is 000.............1 does not fit into the pattern"* - exactly, they can't, but you won't get an 8-byte memory address like 1 because it's not a multiple of 8.  Hope it's clear now.  Cheers

Comment: If a number is a multiple of 8(2 to the power of 3), then three bits from the right will always be clear -> This is the clincher.  If a number is a multiple of 16(2 to the power of 4), then four bits from the right will always be clear. .... If a number is a multiple of 2 to the power of k, then k bits from the right will always be clear.
Never noticed this magic on numbers !!

Comment: @PraveenNvs: yes, you've got it now :-)